# How to automatically scroll horizontally as page width increase

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, scroll

I am building a website that expands horizontally as user takes action like http://portal.azure.com style. When they click a button(from a list) in one div, the details of the selected items appear in another div beside it. this can get really long and over flow the mother div.

I am looking for a way i can automatically scroll the page to the right most edge when a new div overflows.

layout

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto">
  <div layout="row">
    <div class="col" style="width: 400px">
    </div>

    //SHOWN DYNAMICALLY
    <div class="col" style="width: 400px">
    </div>

    //SHOWN DYNAMICALLY
    <div class="col" style="width: 400px">
    </div>

    //SHOWN DYNAMICALLY
    <div class="col" style="width: 400px">
    </div>

    //SHOWN DYNAMICALLY
    <div class="col" style="width: 400px">
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see above, the first div shows by default but the other divs appear based on user interaction. 
By the time the 3 div appears, it overflows.
How can i scroll to the right edge anytime it over flows? (you should really check out http://portal.azure.com to see what im talking about)

PS: i am using AngularJS. I am not using jquery. But i dont mind including it if its the only option

Comment: @vedantTerker Yes i currently have that over flow property set. but i ant the div to slide to the right most edge when it overflows

Comment: set some `height` in pixels for each `div` and add `overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden;`

Comment: use bootstrap it will make it easy using grid classes.

Comment: @ivanStefanov i don't have a problem with the overflow. i just want the overflown div to scroll automatically to the right when the overflow is applied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use plain Javascript for keeping the scroll to right.

Something like this:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("row");
myDiv.scrollLeft = myDiv.scrollWidth;
```

---

You need to fire the above function every time you add a new `div`. That way it will always automatically be scrolled when `div`s are dynamically added.

You will need to hook up the `DOMNodeInserted` event on your container. The function will be called whenever a `div` is added to your `row` container. This way you will not have to change anything in your existing code.

Here is a very simple example with dynamically added `div`s:

```js
var num = 1, 
    btn = document.getElementById('btn'), 
    row = document.getElementById("row");

scroller(); // fire teh scroller right away for initial scroll

// function to keep it scrolled towards right
// function scroller() { row.scrollLeft = row.scrollWidth; }

// edited to add simple animation
function scroller() { 
    var maxScroll = row.scrollWidth - row.clientWidth; // required to stop
    row.scrollLeft += 2; 
    if (row.scrollLeft < maxScroll) {
     timer = window.setTimeout(scroller, 1000 / 60);
    } 
}

// hook up event to call scroller whenever an element is dynamically added
row.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", scroller);

// for demo to simluate dynamically adding divs
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("class", "col");
    num += 1; newDiv.innerText = num;
    row.appendChild(newDiv);
});
```

```css
div[layout] {
    width: 500px; height: 140px; white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden; overflow-x: auto;
}
div.col { height: 140px; width: 400px; display: inline-block; text-align:center; }
div { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div id="row" layout="row"><div class="col">1</div></div>
<button id="btn">Add</button>
```

**Edit**: Added simple animation using `setTimeout` (in order to keep jQuery away). Ideally you should be using `requestAnimationFrame` or a suitable library if you are already using one.

Comment: Would this work if the `div.col` are dynamically added?

Comment: Wrap the 2-liner in a function, and call whenever you are adding a `div`.

Comment: @RaymondAtivie: There. I have updated the answer to include a sample demo for dynamically added divs.

Comment: Works! 
any idea how i can make the scroll animated?

Comment: @RaymondAtivie: Updated the answer to add a simple animation.

Comment: Awesome.... but minor bug... i cant scroll back without it scrolling me to the end again

Comment: @RaymondAtivie: Ooops! I didn't notice that. Give me some time, I shall fix that once I am finished with my current task at hand.

Comment: @RaymondAtivie: Fixed animation problem. I did a silly mistake. Difference of scrollwidth and scrollLeft was not taken into account.